# Parse JSON data using CodeIgniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, json

I am a newbie for Codeigniter, I want to parse JSON data in this framework, Please give me some tutorial or Example for that.

I have done JSON Parsing with Android... Please Help Me with That PHP Framework.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It's PHP. This task does not require any CodeIgniter features. Just pure PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP has it's own JSON functions (i.e. it's framework agnostic) that you can use for manipulating JSON: http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

To convert JSON into PHP array/object use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php